# No data gets transmitted via drf-nested-routers PUT

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I try to update a object in my database via a PUT to my django backend.

The url I call is a PUT to:

```
API_HOST + '/vehicles/V-123'
```

It is routed like this to my update method:

```
from Tiresets.views import TiresetsSet
from Vehicles.views import VehiclesSet
from rest_framework_nested import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=True)
router.register(r'vehicles', VehiclesSet, base_name='vehicles')

bundles_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'vehicles', lookup='vehicles')
bundles_router.register(r'tiresets', TiresetsSet, base_name='tiresets')

urlpatterns = router.urls + bundles_router.urls
```

It also correctly jumps into the update method of my `Vehicles.views` but I can't get any data from `request.DATA`. I also made sure, that the data is correctly sent.

My update function:

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):

    data = request.DATA # <=== Here I don't get any data!!!
```

Anyone an idea what I might got wrong here?

Comment: What version of DRF are you using, what data are you sending, and what parsers are you using? It would be useful to see more of the view set.

Answer (score 1):

You might try:
`data = request.data`
as described here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/